# Spreading a rumour to at least x people with a minimum probability p

Tags: graph-theory

I have the following problem:

Consider an undirected weighted graph G where the weight of an edge between nodes a and b represents the probability of a message being passed from node a to node b (or from node b to node a).

Given G, I need to choose the n-th nodes that can spread a rumor to at least x other nodes and such that the probability of the rumor being passed to each of these other x nodes is at least p > 0.

Is there any algorithm that provides the list of nodes that meet these two conditions?

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Just to clarify: Suppose I choose a node $v$ to start the rumor, and we have node $u$ that is a neighbor of $v$ of weight $1/2$, and node $w$ that is a neighbor of $u$ of weight $1/3$.  If there is no other way for the rumor to go from $v$ to $w$, is the probability the rumor spreads from $v$ to $w$ $1/6$?  Thanks.

Comment: @Tyler Seacrest:  Yes :)

Comment: Interesting problem which I don't know how to solve!  Would be interested in an answer.